# Ext.util.JSONP.request output is undefined

Tags: jsonp

i'm trying to get this example to work:

```
Ext.util.JSONP.request({
url: 'http://www.mydomain.de/service/data.php',
callbackKey: 'callback',

callback: function(data) {
     alert(data.title);
}
```

});

with the following php:

```
<?php
$callback = $_REQUEST['callback'];
$output = array('title' => 'Apple');
if ($callback) {
    header('Content-Type: text/javascript');
    echo $callback . '(' . json_encode($output) . ');';
} else {
    header('Content-Type: application/x-json');
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

?>

If i'm trying to alert the title, all I get is 'undefined'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try get result in success event. I'm not sure about callback event.

This work with me. Hope this help.

```
Ext.util.JSONP.request({
    url: 'http://localhost:8000/test/',
    params: {
        key: 'data'
    },
    success: function (response, request) {     
        console.log(response);
    },
    failure: function (response, request) {
        console.log(request);
    }
});
```